# How to make client side image resize function reusable

Tags: javascript

HTML Template

```
<html>
<form>
    Image to resize: <input type="file" id="getImage"><br><br>
    </form>
    <img src="." id="image">
<html>
```

Java Script

```
 <script>
    document.getElementById('getImage').onchange = imageResize(60,60);

 var imageResize = function (Width, Height) {


 //-- GET FILE FROM FORM       
    var selectedFile = this.files[0];
//-- GET BASE 64

    File.prototype.convertToBase64 = function (callback) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            callback(e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(this);
    };

    selectedFile.convertToBase64(function (base64) {

 //-- MAKE IMAGE        
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = base64;
//-- PUSH INTO CANVAS           
        img.onload = function () {        
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.width = Width; // If i change Width & Height to numbers it works!!
            canvas.height = Height;
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, Width, Height);

//-- SHOW IMAGE ON PAGE
            document.getElementById("image").src = canvas.toDataURL();
        };
    });
};  

 </script>
```

Just above I'm setting the canvas width and height to 60x60 but i cant use the variables I've passed in without getting an error, and I cant figure out why. the error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you should attach the event listener to `input` element.but instead you attached to `img` element

and you also want to access the files inside the `event listener`,so you should pass `this` reference to the `listener`

and the way you are attaching the event is not right.
your are doing this  `document.getElementById('getImage').onchange = imageResize(60,60);`

this is wrong as it will execute the `imageResize()` and assigns the result to on change event.

actually you should attach reference of the function like below

```
document.getElementById('getImage').onchange = imageResize;
```

i edited your code a little.
try this snippet.

```js
var imageResize = function(Width, Height, files) {

  var selectedFile = files[0];

  File.prototype.convertToBase64 = function(callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      callback(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this);
  };

  selectedFile.convertToBase64(function(base64) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = base64;
    img.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvas.width = Width;
      canvas.height = Height;
      ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, Width, Height);
      document.getElementById("image").src = canvas.toDataURL();
    };
  });
};
var file = document.getElementById('getImage');
file.onchange = function() {
  imageResize(160, 160, this.files);
};
```

```html
<form>
  Image to resize:
  <input type="file" id="getImage">
  <br>
  <br>
</form>
<img src="." id="image">
```

Comment: I can clearly see it working when i run the code snippet but i cant get it to work locally in the project for some reason, its making me crazy

Comment: The script was loading before the DOM was ready, junior error on my behalf, thank you for your solution to this issue Paven.